# logging facilities for realtime and non realtime applications

Tags: c++, linux, logging, real-time

We're developing both std and realtime applications that run on a RT-Linux.
question is, what would be an *efficient way of logging application traces from both realtime and non-realtime processes*?

By *effecient*, I mean that the process of logging application traces shouldn't cause RT-perf hit by increasing latency, etc.

Traces should ideally be stored into a single file with timestamp, to make it easier to track interaction between processes.

Comment: Why don't you log to a UDP listener on another machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are on linux, you can use [syslog()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog) :

> openlog() opens a connection to the system logger for a program.

this means your program forwards messages to another program, which can be of low priority.

If you want something more fancy, then [boost logging](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log1/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: I think `syslog` will cause to store app log into a log file per application?

Comment: syslog has the idea of a "facility" and then sylog's config (/etc/syslog.conf or /etc/rsyslog.conf ?) decides how to handle each facility (and can apply other rules e.g based on severity).  You can have multiple apps logging as a single facility and having all their log messages put into one file.

Comment: we've been using syslog and boost log for a while now, and things are going pretty well. Of course you need to bear in mind that logging traces (e.g. with boost log) in the RT app will have a perf. hit, i.e. increased latency.

Answer (score 4):

For real time Logging I'll advise use different aproaches than bare logging to files. Writing to files a lot of information **will** hurt your performance.

I can advice other more lighter mechanismS:

- Use statistics/counters to get filling what your application is doing
- Write/encode logs in some binary format to be processed offline. This binary format may be more compact and thus lighter.